# C# combobox overridden ToString

Tags: c#, combobox, tostring, overriding

I am experiencing some problems while working with ComboBox.

The display member for my combobox is not being populated by the ***overridden ToString*** method of class MAP.

Here is my code:

**Form1.cs:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    ...  
    ...      
    MAPList MAP = new MAPList();  
    comboBox1.DataSource = MAP.All;  
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code";  
    ...  
    ...  
}
```

**MAPList.cs:**

```
public class MAPList {  
    public readonly List<MAP> All;

    public MAPList() {
        All = new List<MAP>();

        var MapData = // Getting map data

        foreach(MAP m in MapData) {
            All.Add(new Map(m.Name, m.Code));
        }
    }
}
```

**MAP.cs:**

```
public class MAP {
    public readonly string Name;

    private string code;
    public string Code { get { return code; } }

    public RadioCode(string Name, string Code) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.code = Code;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Format("{0}: {1}", Name, Code);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship? I don't see you call the Object Map anywhere

Comment: So what's displaying instead? Just "MAP"?

Comment: You're setting ValueMember to the property "Code". Nowhere will your .ToString override get invoked. Instead of overriding ToString, just use that code exposed as a instance property and bind to that.

Comment: @Dan Tao: No. The value for "Code"

Comment: @vodkhang: doesn't overridden ToString control what user sees in combobox??

Comment: @Ruby - exactly. You're binding to the property "Code", hence it displays code. Bind to a property that returns String.Format("{0}: {1}", Name, Code); You bind to a string value, why would the compiled call .ToString on a string? @Dan Tao's answer is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ToString will not be called if you set `ValueMember`.  If you do not set `ValueMember` it will work as expected but then of course `Code` will not be used as the selected value of the ComboBox.

Alternatively, if you wish to use `ValueMember` you may also want to set `DisplayMember`.  You can create a property on your `MAP` that is used for display, i.e.:

```
public class MAP
{
    public readonly string Name;

    private string code;

    public string Code { get { return code; } }
    public string Display { get { return ToString(); } }

    public MAP(string Name, string Code)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.code = Code;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}: {1}", Name, Code);
    }
}
```

In the form you can then set `DisplayMember`:

```
MAPList MAP = new MAPList();
comboBox1.DataSource = MAP.All;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've set your `ValueMember` property to "Code", so the values in the combobox are not your `Map` objects but rather the strings corresponding to their `Code` properties.

If you remove this line:

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code";
```

...it will work as you expect.

If you want the ComboBox to *display* its items according to your `Map` type's `ToString` method, then [Jakob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664956/c-combobox-overridden-tostring/3665016#3665016) is right on: create a property on your `Map` type that provides a string formatted exactly how you want it, and set the `DisplayMember` property of the ComboBox to the name of *this* property.

Comment: I agree and it was exactly how I implemented it before. But my requirements forces me to retrive the value of "Code" when I do comboBox1.SelectedValue not the formatted string.

Comment: @Ruby: See Jakob's answer; I think that provides exactly the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

this could be because u r using ValueMember. use **DisplayMember** Property, add another property on the Map class in the get of this property return the formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but if someone wants to use ToString() without creating a property to just call ToString(), you'll have to explicitly set the DisplayMember value to an empty string like this:

**Form1.cs:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    ...  
    ...      
    MAPList MAP = new MAPList();  
    comboBox1.DataSource = MAP.All;  
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code"; 
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "";  // Explicitly set it to an empty String
    ...  
    ...  
}
```

Comment: FYI, you need to set `.ValueMember` before `.DisplayMember`. I was doing it wrong and still had the problem. Once I switched it was fixed!